# What is this type of declaration (snake.x) in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am learning JavaScript as well as its library jQuery. I don't know why this type of declaration (snake.x) is allowed without "let" or anything. Here is my code

```
$(document).ready(function () {
   let snake = $('.snake')
   let fruit = $('.fruit')

   snake.x = 0
   snake.y = 0
   fruit.x = 2
   fruit.y = 3

console.log(snake.x+1) // print 1
console.log(fruit.y + 2) // print 5

}
```

Comment: It is quite hard to know how to help you here, as it is not entirely clear what you want to archive. Note that in JavaScript, if a variable does not exist and you want to assign it a value, it is typically assigned to the `window` object. If you do `hello = 'world'`, you can always call `window.hello` and you will be returned `'world'`.

Comment: `$()` returns an object. The properties `x` and `y` are being assigned to those objects. `console.log(typeof snake)`

Comment: @TheKeymaster, your example works, but when I type `hello.x = 'world'` and try to `console.log(hello.x)` or even `console.log(typeof(hello.x))`, it says "hello is not defined".

Comment: Because what TheKeyMaster is telling you has no relevancy here with regard to the objects you are asking about. Do some research into how to work with properties of objects

Answer (score 0):

Javascript allows declaring variables like that, but this will attach those variables to the global scope, so its same thing as

```js
snake.x = 5;

// same as
window.snake.x = 5
```

Comment: Even if they declare snake with let before like they did in the code posted?

Comment: `snake` is defined in a closure. It is not the same as `window.snake` which would be undefined. In addition anything declared with `let` or `const` do not get added to window s properties the same as with `var`

Comment: If I put "let" in front of snake.x, it won't work @cloned

Comment: @dohuynhnam That's because `snake` is an object. `snake.x` is the property named "x" of the already defined object snake